# How to paste a text to the browser?

Tags: string, browser, xul, paste

Following [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Clipboard#section_2) I was able to retrieve data form the clipboard.

But I have no idea (nither there's something in the API) about how to insert my string into [the xul browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser) (say, when the user open the 'edit' menu and click 'paste').

Any idea?

**--update**

There's a `cmd_paste` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/List_of_commands), but there's no hint if I can (and how to) use it to paste in a browser. Also the [browser's API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser) available documentation have nothing about.

I tried make it work creating a browser, setting the `command` attribute (not sure if it exists, [the API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser) says nothing, but it's a wiki not much reliable) and a button to paste:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window width="400" height="300"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <browser id="mybrowser" command="cmd_paste" type="content" src="http://www.google.com/" flex="1" />
    <button label="TEST PASTE" command="document.getElementById('mybrowser').doCommand();" />

</window>
```

Nothing happens when I press the button (with data on my clipboard, and a text field selected inside the browser).

**--in the xulrunner source**

within toolkit.jar, at content/global/editMenuOverlay.xul there's the definition:

```
<command id="cmd_paste" oncommand="goDoCommand('cmd_paste')"/>
```

but no "goDoCommand" method is defined there, nither in the only javascript file included: `editMenuOverlay.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the goDoCommand (see the question update) I found out that the function was in the globalOverlay.js file.

So I added to my Xul:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://global/content/globalOverlay.js" />
```

and used the goDoCommand command.

Not yet sure if it's the best or even correct approach to add this js to my Xul, but look likes ok.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a "paste" command? Couldn't you just retrieve the data from the clipboard using the tutorial you found and copy it into the currently focused text elements when the past button is pressed?

Comment: "copy it into the currently focused text elements when the paste button is pressed" it's what I'm trying to do, and also what a paste command do. Now, how do I do it? (note that I'm in my own application, not in Firefox, and I have no paste button ready for use, so I need to do one).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I meant doing something like : 

var clipBoardText = getClipBoardText();

myTextBox.value = clipBoardText;

But I never worked with browser so I do not know how to set text value in a browser text box.